# Android Studio no me deja lanzar la aplicación

Tags: android, gradle, emulación

tengo un problema al lanzar la aplicación al emulador me da el siguiente erro:

files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\5f9566675a50af79c3733eedebae6a94\res\values\values.xml:1454:5-1461:13: AAPT: error: :style>.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
11 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 8 up-to-date

Comment: infiero por tu traza que usas gradle, por favor haz lo que te dice para tener una mejor traza, agrégale `--stacktrace` como argumento para que te de la traza del error

Comment: no se como hacerlo me puede indicar por favor

Comment: si lo corres desde consola y suponiendo que la tarea que corriste es build `gradlew build  --stacktrace` sino agrega los detalles de como lo corres a la pregunta

Comment: corro esta opcion * Try:Run with --stacktrace pero no pasa nada me sigue diciendo al momento de emular que  C:\Users\Cristian\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\5f9566675a50af79c3733eedebae6a94\res\values\values.xml:1454:5-1461:13: AAPT: error: :style>.

Comment: En el build.gradle coloco implementation'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'... le doy Sync Now y todo bien no me da error

Comment: y si corres la línea que te puse?

Comment: donde la debo correr???

Comment: como te dije, en consola, en la raíz de tu proyecto

Comment: disculpa no se como  ingreso a la consola....seria en file...settings ?

Comment: Alt+F12 si estás en Windows si tienes los bindings por defecto del IntelliJ Idea ( que te preseleccionará el direcotio raíz ), si no usas IDE, tecla de windows y escribes cmd (y luego haces cd hasta el directorio raíz)

Comment: Gracias ya descubrí cual fue mi error...estaba en styles un par de lineas mal y bueno me rompí la cabe todo el día en una tontera

Comment: Sería genial que pusieras tu respuesta, a´si le ahorras el tiempo a alguien después